# select from firebird db insert into mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysqli, firebird

I am trying to get some data form a Firebird db and put into a MySql db using PHP.
My problem is that my SELECT have 3847 rows and the code just INSERT 981 rows!!!
Here is my code, I took off connections and some other things to write here because everything is right...Thanks for helping!

```
$res=ibase_query($conexao, 
"select
p.id_processo as ID ,
p.alteravel1 as PLACA,
p.titproc as TITPROC,
p.data_inicio as RECEPCIONADO,
p.dt_atu_geral as GERAL,
p.numproc as N_PROCESSO,
p.id_cli,
p.id_adv,
p.id_fase,
p.vara as VARA,
fo.nm_foro as FORO,
cd.nm_cidade as CIDADE,
uf.nm_estado as ESTADO
from processo p
left join pessoa pss on p.id_adv = pss.id_pessoa
left join foro fo on p.id_foro = fo.id_foro
left join cidade cd on fo.id_cidade = cd.id_cidade
left join estado uf on cd.id_estado = uf.id_estado
where pss.nome <> 'JORGE LUIS CONFORTO' and
p.status = '0'"
);
$sql="create table if not exists processo1 (
id int(40) not null primary key,
placa varchar(100),
titproc varchar(100),
data_recepcionado datetime,
data_atual datetime,
n_processo varchar(100),
id_cli int(40),
id_adv int(40),
id_fase int(40),
vara int(40),
foro varchar(100),
cidade varchar(100),
estado varchar(100)
)";

mysqli_query($conexao1, $sql);

while ($escrever=ibase_fetch_assoc($res)){
$id = $escrever['ID'];
$placa = $escrever['PLACA'];
$titproc = $escrever['TITPROC'];
$dtin = $escrever['RECEPCIONADO'];
$dtatu = $escrever['GERAL'];
$nproc = $escrever['N_PROCESSO'];
$cli = $escrever['ID_CLI'];
$adv = $escrever['ID_ADV'];
$fase = $escrever['ID_FASE'];
$vara = $escrever['VARA'];
$foro = $escrever['FORO'];
$cidade = $escrever['CIDADE'];
$estado = $escrever['ESTADO'];

$query = "insert into processo1 (
id,
placa,
titproc,
data_recepcionado,
data_atual,
n_processo,
id_cli,
id_adv,
id_fase,
vara,
foro,
cidade,
estado) 
values (
'$id',
'$placa',
'$titproc',
'$dtin',
'$dtatu',
'$nproc',
'$cli',
'$adv',
'$fase',
'$vara',
'$foro',
'$cidade',
'$estado'
)";

mysqli_query($conexao1, $query);
}
```

Comment: [mysqli_error()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) is your friend, what does it tell you the problem is?

Comment: Could it be that You run out of memory or You get timeouted?

Comment: It is not memory or timeout. I change select to SELECT TOP 50 and the INSERT returns 10 rows!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should always check for errors after running each query.

It is likely that your inserts are failing for some reason. The exact reason could be anything, but if at least this way you should be notified of any errors with the inserts that are failing.

```
if (!$mysqli_query($query)) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help Anigel!
The problem is that it do not print any error message, seems like everything is ok...

Comment: Are you displaying errors and have you checked the server error log? It sounds like you may be being terminated before all the inserts completed. This would normally be due to exceeding maximum execution time or allowed memory.

Comment: Yeah! I think that it is exceeding maximum memory, because I change all the maximum time I could in php.ini...Thaks again

Comment: I tried to select top 500 to test if the problem is memory, and the insert returns 159 rows, so the problem must be in while...almost sure!

Comment: Hey...I discovered that the code is not inserting rows that have any field with special character like ´~ªº, do you have any idea how o solve it? The big mistery is that if I try to insert the row manual, by the prompt of mysql, it works...it just do not insert using php code...any idea?